# The print problem: How to show it is not decidable?

Tags: computer-science, computability

I wonder the following reduction is correct.

I'm trying to show that the following problem **"PRINT_BLANK"** is not decidable.

**Input:** (a coding of) Turing machine M.
**Question:** Does the machine never types "blank" on the stripe when it runs on x?

An attempt for reduction: $AcceptProblem \leq PrintBlank: f(\langle M,x\rangle)= M'.$

Given $M$ and $x$, we'll construct $M'$: For an input $y$ for $M'_x$, $M'_x$ simulates running of M on $w$. if $M$ accepts $w$, $M'_x$ writes "blank" and accepts y, otherwise it writes $x$ itself on the tape and rejects.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: You made a mistake: what happens when M already writes a blank during it's execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: to make your reduction work, you should alter $M$ slightly, can you figure out how? If not, let me know.

EDIT: What happens when M already writes a blank during it's execution.

Comment: It's not even a hint :)

Comment: @Jozef, read my comment, can you figure it out now?

Comment: no, can you please extend your answer?

Comment: Oh I get your hint- I can writ # instead of blank on running on M, but besides that the reduction isn't correct any way, what if M does not stops? right?

Comment: That does not matter, since you are not running $M$, you are creating an other machine that runs $M$, these two situations are entirely different! Think about it!

About my hint: Indeed, that is the only mistake you made! In the transition function of $M$ you have to replace the blank symbol with something different. Apart from that, your reduction is correct.

Comment: yes, but I wrote "otherwise" it "writes..."- what is this otherwise? if it rejected- fine, if it didn't stop with a result and in loop, also $M'$ would be in loop and until it doesn't stop it doesn't write blank, and it's fine. I should just emphasize it in my proof, do you get what I'm saying?

Comment: Writing otherwise does not matter, since you only have to output a blank when $M$ halts and accepts. You are not running $M'$ you are simply constructing it. You are just given an instance for one problem, and generating an instance for another problem. In this case you construct $M'$, but you do not run $M$ while constructing $M'$ do you?